# slick error: Wrong number of type parameters. Expected: 0, actual: 1

Tags: scala, orm, slick

When I follow the slick official tutorial, I keep getting errors:

> Wrong number of type parameters. Expected: 0, actual: 1

Here is my code:

```
class Suppliers(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)](tag, "SUPPLIERS") {
  def id = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey) // This is the primary key column
  def name = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
  def street = column[String]("STREET")
  def city = column[String]("CITY")
  def state = column[String]("STATE")
  def zip = column[String]("ZIP")
  // Every table needs a * projection with the same type as the table's type parameter
  def * = (id, name, street, city, state, zip)
}
```

and my **build.sbt**:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

val akkaHttpV = "10.1.1"

val akkaV = "2.6.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaV,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % akkaV,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % akkaHttpV,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % akkaHttpV,
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.3.0",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-codegen" % "3.3.0",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.3.0",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1206-jdbc42",
)
```

I don`t know how to fix it , so help me please!

Comment: Hello! It looks like the code is from the [getting started page of the manual](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.0/gettingstarted.html#schema) (which is backed by [this source file](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/v3.3.0/doc/code/FirstExample.scala#L24-L48)). I can't see anything wrong with what you have. What line of code is the error shown against?